# How do i add html tags in a dynamic render and still load values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that takes in a number "n", and I am trying to dynamically render an item n times, but I need to put an HTML tag inside this render. How do i get it to render the tag with its effect instead of as a string?

Example:

```
//variables
props.multiple = a number (for example 2)
props.base1 = a number (lets say 5)
props.exp1 = also a number (lets say 3)

const Multiple = (props) => {
    let result = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < (props.multiple - 1); i++){
        console.log("i: "+i);
        result += `${props.base1}<sup>${props.exp1}</sup> + `;
    }
    console.log("result: "+result);
    return <span>{result}</span>;
}
```

I want this to render like this:

```
<span>
   {props.base1}<sup>{props.exp1}</sup> +
   {props.base1}<sup>{props.exp1}</sup> +
   {props.base1}<sup>{props.exp1}</sup> +
   ... however many times n is equal to
</span>
```

looking like this on the webpage:
`5^3 + 5^3 + 5^3 + ... n times`

however right now my html tags are either being printed as a string or the render is just `[object Object` instead of the actual values. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's true because you are appending to the `results` variable all strings hence `props.base1` and `props.exp1` are coerced to string too.

What you probably want to do is to append JSX elements to that `results` variable and then render it on the DOM, you can do that as the following:

```
let result = [];
for(let i = 0; i < (props.multiple - 1); i++){
    console.log("i: "+i);
    result.push(<>{props.base1}<sup>{props.exp1}</sup>+</>);
}
```

This way what are you doing is fullfilling the `results` array with all **JSX Elements**, hence all the HTML tags will be rendered as expected. `<>` and `</>` refers to a `React.Fragment` ([ref here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)) because you dont want to append another JSX element to each child, like a `div`.

Comment: On a side note, I am rendering this <Multiple> component in my parent component, but for some reason all my console.log statements in Multiple are infinitely printing, do you know what the cause of this is?

Comment: Depending on your application, it might be re-rendering so each time React re-renders the parent component, the child component is re-rendered (hence re-executed) so it will console.log "infinitely" (it should not be actually infinite though)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your example is that you are forming a string while you should be forming React elements. Therefore, you need to build an array of elements rather than concatenating to a string:

```js
const MyFunction = ({ multiple, base1, exp1 }) => {
  
  const format = () => <React.Fragment>{base1}<sup>{exp1}</sup> + </React.Fragment> // or <></>, but not supported here
  
  return (
    <span>{_.times(multiple, format)}</span>
  );
};



const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');
ReactDOM.render(<MyFunction multiple={2} base1={5} exp1={3} />, domContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

As another thought I would suggest to not loop like that and append to a string, but rather use something functional like lodash as suggested in the snippet to build the array more declaratively.